# how do I display hex data in well aligned(like as tabular format) in windows application

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to display the contents of bbbb.txt file to hex format into `richTextBox2`.

```cs
case 0:
{
     groupBox3.Enabled =false;
     label3.Enabled = false;
     label4.Enabled = false;
     btn_CompareRec.Enabled = false;
     btn_CompareRef.Enabled = false;
     byte[] mybytes = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\bbbb.txt");
     string bb = "";
     int i = 0;
     int numBytesToRead = 200;
     while (numBytesToRead > 0)
     {
         if (mybytes[i].ToString("X") != "20")
         {
              bb = bb + mybytes[i].ToString("X") + "";
              // bb.PadLeft(10, '-');
         }
         i = i + 1;
         numBytesToRead = numBytesToRead - 1;
     }
     richTextBox2.Text = bb;
}
```

It's displaying inside the textbox but how would I display it in tabular format ? (just like any hex editor)

Comment: Use a fixed width font (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font)

Comment: Do you want it tabular for each "Blank space" and "New Line"? If so What will be the maximum length for single word?

Comment: Mitch, its good but help me for implementing it to my code.

Comment: 0.00      1.00000000  0.00     1.00000000  
0.10      1.10517092  0.00     1.00000000
0.10      1.10517092  0.00     1.00000000 the hex data should be disply like this format like base addresses

Comment: @rocky: you should add a formatted example of what you're trying to accomplish in your question. A "well-aligned" format isn't too specific really.

Comment: @Groo:Actually I want to take .txt/.doc file from the system, now open the file and read it and display in hex format in richtextbox2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this;

Add `else` Part in If Condition

```
if (mybytes[i].ToString("X") != "20")
{
    bb = bb + mybytes[i].ToString("X");                 
}
else
{
    //EDIT
    bb .PadLeft(8, '0'); // considering 64 will  be maxsize

    bb = bb + " ";
}
```

Comment: hey its working but I need to add further customization

Comment: means I should add padding between each character, It should display like this with equidistance- 000012      00002F       00023     00004D

Comment: you will understand better if you see this link http://home.gna.org/bless/bless-manual/ch05s03.html see the Standard offset-hex-ascii view

Comment: Is the number of maximum continuous bytes between two spaces are know to you ?

Comment: Suppose,if we choose 5 as maximum then it should be same till the end. So we can choose any maximum value but it should be same till the end.

Comment: FF should be the maximum value.

Comment: move your mouse near to Down side arrow by the top of answer and you can will "Tick Mark", click on it ( Accept as Answer)

Comment: That is what I was trying to tell you to if we fix padding to 8 and if your file has continuous byte without space say 12 then that part will have different space. So go for the larger value, I would suggest 64.

Comment: sorry to say, but I dont know how to do that?